# PubNub : Route to push notification service even if device is in the foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, pubnub

I was wondering if its possible, using PubNub to route a message as a push notification, even if the app is running in the foreground?

One way that I can think to do this is to:

- Handle any specific routing and events that need to happen first.
- Check the push note portion of the message and send a l[ocal device notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html). Alternatively any custom UI, etc could be done here.

Comment: What do you mean by route? Do you want to slide new message from top edge of screen like push notification?

Comment: @AlexZd We're using the PubNub fall back to push notification service, which only sends a push notification if the device is in the background. Foregrounded apps have messages routed normally through pubnub.

Comment: Removed by comments and provided official answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PubNub *does* send the push notification when the app is in the foreground. In fact, PubNub (the mobile push notification server) does not know if the device is foreground, background or not running at all. So the push notification is always sent to the device either way.

See the following PubNub Developer Community article, [Sending APNS and GCM Messages to Subscribers and Mobile Push Notification Services in One API Call](http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/498/sending-apns-and-gcm-messages-to-subscribers-and-mobile-push-notification-services-in-one-api-call), for more details.

Also refer to the [PubNub iOS Mobile Push Gateway Tutorial for Realtime Apps](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/mobile-gateway-sdk-v4). These docs are about to get a major upgrade in terms of completeness.

Comment: I removed my comments above and provided as a formal answer. But if you still have further questions, please provide full details to support@pubnub.com - cheers!